# How to save information ( Swift application )

Tags: ios, random, save

I am developing an iOS application which generate random inspirational quote every day. At the moment when I close the app, open it again and click on the button which generates the daily quote, it shows me a new one.

Can you help me, how can I save the same quote all over the day and when the day is over generate a new quote. I mean at 00:00 o'clock in the morning.

I want to keep 1 quote per day, not 1 quote for every time I open the app.

Comment: You will want to look at [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i) and [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/). No offense, but you're asking a very basic thing that's well documented, perhaps you invest some time into research before asking on SO.

Comment: I started with swift a week ago. I am still new and do not know how to do these things. Sorry if my question is too basic for you, but your answer is unclear for me. I would appreciate if you give me an example or simple code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have some time on my hands and I can provide you a small tutorial on how to save data to the user defaults.

You will want to save the date on which you create a quote right after you created it and then each time your app goes to foreground check against that. Obviously you want to only remember the day, not the hours, minutes and seconds. Here's a small function for that:

```
func makeCleanToday() -> NSDate {
    let today = NSDate()
    let comps = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: today)
    return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(comps)!
}
```

Note that this forcibly unwraps the date on the last line, but this is fine here, since I do nothing that could lead to `dateFromComponents` returning `nil`.

The next two lines you will always call right after you created your quote:

```
let cleanToday = makeCleanToday()
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(cleanToday, forKey: "MyAppDateKey")
```

Obviously you should use a better key to identify this (I suggest defining a constant somewhere for this). This saves your date (only day, month and year) in the app's user defaults.

Next time your app goes into the foreground (use the app delegate for this), then do this here:

```
if let savedDate:NSDate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("MyAppDateKey") as? NSDate {
    let cleanToday = makeCleanToday()
    if savedDate.earlierDate(cleanToday) == savedDate {
        // create new sentence

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(cleanToday, forKey: "MyAppDateKey")
    }
} else {
    // create new sentence

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(makeCleanToday(), forKey: "MyAppDateKey")
}
```

Please note that I added the two `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject....` lines here just to illustrate what happens. You will probably have that code already in your quote creation method, like I told you above to do. Also, the `else` part of this is for when you run the app the first time. Then you don't have anything saved in the user defaults, so `savedDate`is `nil` and you have to create your quote as normal.

Lastly a general remark: Using `NSCalendar` is relatively expensive (though it is designed for this scenario), so you shouldn't use it, for example, when filling cells in a table or something (because that might negatively affect frame rate during scrolling). In this case it's perfectly fine (*relatively* being the keyword here), I just wanna let you know before you eventually advance with your coding to a point where you run into this. :) Same is true for date formatters.

Oh, and regarding the comment: No need to say sorry, I just wanted to let you know how things here on SO are and cushion the fall a bit when you see your question getting downvoted. I hope this could help you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate it !

Comment: You're very welcome. If that solved your problem, maybe accept and/or upvote my answer. :) (I take it you're new on SO, that's typically what you do here. I'd appreciate it.)

Comment: Oh, haha, I forgot about this. Nevermind then. Best of luck with your project!

Comment: I just happened to look it further up, and just for the record: Upvoting needs the 15 reputation. You can always accept answers (the little checkmark next to an answer). In fact, even you as question author gain reputation by accepting someone else's answer. See [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).